# How to compute an index in r?

Tags: r, indexing, group-by, row

It is my first time I am asking a question in this great community. I am trying to calculate an index on a data.frame, show them by borough or neighborhood and plot. Which code suited the most?

Here is an example of a data set I have.
albo, aegy = mosquito species, house = house prospected, The house index computed is the (number of positive houses/number of prospected houses)*100. a positive house is a house where at least one mosquito was found (value!=0) HI = (7/11)*100 = 63.63 for total (11 = number of houses prospected, and 7 = number of positive houses in total)

```
borough neighborhood    concession  albo    aegyp   Total_albo_aegyp
a1  mendong                1         1        5            6
a1  mendong                2         5        2            7
a1  mendong                3         2        1            3
a1  tam tam                4         0        0            0
a2  tam tam                5         4        6            10
a2  obili                  6         0        1             1
a2  obili                  7         0        0             0
a3  acacia                 8         3        7             10
a4  melen                  9         1        1             2
a4  melen                  10        0        5             5
a4  polytech               11        8        0             10

HIcommune <- concessiondata %>% 
  group_by(commune) %>% 
  summarise(
  Mean = mean(concessiondata$total_aedes_albo_aegypti!=0),
  HIY = sum(concessiondata1$total_aedes_albo_aegypti!=0)/length(concessiondata1$total_aedes_albo_aegypti))

  Houseindex_total <- concessiondata1[, Mean := mean(total_aedes_albo_aegypti!=0), by = "commune"]


  ## This is how the results should look like

borough albo HI aegy HI Total_albo_aegyp_HI
a1        75       75         75
a2        33.33    66.66      66.66
a3        100      100        100
a4        66.66    66.66      100
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `dplyr` and `data.table` syntax? Also, please double-check your code. Your sample data doesn't have a column `commune`. Lastly, you don't need to `$`-index columns inside `summarise`. All up, this seems to be more of an issue with understanding basic `dplyr` syntax.

Comment: thanks for your remarks. when I removed the symbol $ in my code, everything goes as well as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there are a couple of general coding/syntax issues with your code.

1. I would advise against mixing `dplyr` and `data.table` syntax.
2. You don't need to `$`-index columns inside `dplyr` verbs.

I would recommend familiarising yourself with one of the many freely available `tidyverse` tutorials to learn the basics of reshaping/manipulating data with `dplyr`/`tidyr`.

That aside, the following reproduces your expected output

```
calc_index <- function(x) sum(x != 0) / length(x) * 100

library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(borough) %>%
    summarise(
        albo_HI = calc_index(albo),
        aegyp_HI = calc_index(aegyp),
        Total_albo_aegyp = calc_index(Total_albo_aegyp))
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#  borough albo_HI aegyp_HI Total_albo_aegyp
#  <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 a1         75       75               75
#2 a2         33.3     66.7             66.7
#3 a3        100      100              100
#4 a4         66.7     66.7            100
```

Or you can use `summarise_all`

```
df %>%
    group_by(borough) %>%
    select(-neighborhood, -concession) %>%
    summarise_all(~calc_index(.x))
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#  borough  albo aegyp Total_albo_aegyp
#  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 a1       75    75               75
#2 a2       33.3  66.7             66.7
#3 a3      100   100              100
#4 a4       66.7  66.7            100
```

Comment: This solution was far better. Thank you for advising me "tidyverse" package as it permit to manipulate data at your convenience.